# Laravel $request->validated() for data that has object datatype inside the request body

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I have used `$request->validated()` to validate request body that only consists of normal key-value pair, but what if the request body has an object inside it?

Example:

```
// this works just fine
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

the return of `$request->validated()` will be only for key1 and key2, but when it comes to body like this:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "object1": {
        "key2.1": "value2.2"
        "key2.2": "value2.2"
     }
}
```

and when I tried to create `object1` record using:

```
object1::create($request->validated())
```

it throwed an error because the `$request->validated()` only validate any normal key-value data and did not dive into the object's property. Any idea to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can use `request->validated()["object"]` to get validated object inside request body, so you don't need to validate every key inside that object anymore.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$request->validate([

    'object1.*.key2.1' => 'required',
    'object1.*.key2.2' => 'required'

]);
```

`'object1.*.key2.1' => 'required'`, the object1 is the key and * is the index

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: @SvenEberth `'object1.*.key2.1' => 'required'`, the object1 is the key and * is the index

Comment: Please add the explanation to the answer, not as comment. Use the [edit] button for that.