# How to make condition to add stock for new product or existing product

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am a beginner in Laravel and I want to create a website to manage stock
I want to create conditions if I want to add stock for products that have been registered or new stock for products that have not been registered/don't have stock yet

```
public function store(StoreStockGudangRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();
        $product_check = StockGudang::where('product_id', $request->product_id)->where('size_id', $request->size_id)->where('color_id', $request->color_id)->get();

        if($product_check == null){
            StockGudang::create($validated);
        }else{
            StockGudang::where('product_id', $request->product_id)->where('size_id', $request->size_id)->where('color_id', $request->color_id)->increment('stock', $request->stock);

        }
        return redirect('/dashboard/stock')->with('success', 'Stock has been added!');
    }
```

Comment: Does the [info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68464332/7644018) possibly help?

Comment: does this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695943/laravel-updateorcreate-method)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function store(StoreStockGudangRequest $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $where = [
        'product_id' => $request->product_id,
        'size_id' => $request->size_id,
        'color_id' => $request->color_id
    ];

    $product_check = StockGudang::query()->where($where)->exists();

    if(! $product_check){
        StockGudang::create($validated);
    } else {
        StockGudang::query()->where($where)->increment('stock', $request->get('stock', 1));
    }
    
    return redirect('/dashboard/stock')->with('success', 'Stock has been added!');
}
```